# IntelliJ equivalent of tooltip to create unknown class/type

Tags: eclipse, types, intellij-idea

In Eclipse, when you type a method or declare a variable and the type is an unknown type, the Eclipse tooltip will let you at a click of a button create that type and place it in whatever package (or even a different project, aka module in intellij).

Is there such functionality in IntelliJ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how it works in Eclipse but in Intellij, it is like this: when you write class/varibale/field/constant name which you don't have and hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, you will see like this popup:
[image], select 'Create Class YourClassName'

And then select the destination for that class:
[image]